# passing arguments to featureUnion transformer_list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parameter-passing, pipeline

I am building a `sklearn` `Pipeline` including a `FeatureUnion`

```
MyPip= Pipeline([
    # other steps 


    ('myunion', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[

            # Pipeline for pulling features from the post's subject line
            ('my_transform1', my_transform()),
            ('my_transform2', my_transform_alt())
            ]))
    )),

])
```

Normally, I could inject parameters into my pipeline using:

```
Params={}

Params.update({'my_step__my_param_name':'my_param_value'})
MyPip.set_params(**Params)
```

But how do I set the parametrs of the feature union transformer_list?

I have tried

```
Params.update({'transform1__my_param_name':'my_param_value'})
Params.update({'myunion__my_transform1__my_param_name':'my_param_value'})
Params.update({'myunion__transformer_list__my_transform1__my_param_name':'my_param_value'})
MyPip.set_params(**Params)
```

but none of them worked.